# Software for knowing the time spent on Kindle device?

Tags: gratis, android, osx, kindle

I need a software which can track the amount of time spent on my Kindle device, so that I can gauge my reading habits.

Device: [Kindle GlareFree Touch 6``(Wi-fi)](http://Kindle%20-%206%22%20Glare-Free%20Touchscreen%20Display,%20Wi-Fi)

If it is compatible with the Kindle Android app, and the OsX Kindle app; then much better.

(I am willing to pay for the app/plugin, bonus points for a gratis one)